# Slow wifi in ubuntu 14.04 with realtek wifi adapter

Tags: 14.04, wireless, realtek

```
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 041e:4055 Creative Technology, Ltd Live! Cam Video IM Pro
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 046d:c318 Logitech, Inc. Illuminated Keyboard
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 003: ID 045e:02d1 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 046d:0a44 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0781:5583 SanDisk Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1b1c:1b05 Corsair 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Don't see anything wifi related. Can you add the output of `lspci` to the question.

Comment: There is no wifi adapter at all in your output. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Are you asking about a USB adapter?

Comment: If i do the terminal command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` nothing shows up

Comment: Yes it is the usb adapater'

Comment: You provide irrelevant information then. You need to post output of `lsusb`. You can remove all that you posted before. It all is not about wireless.

Answer (score 0):

Install another driver this way

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms
```

The new version of this driver should improve things. If that will not help, I have another `dkms` driver in this PPA that should work for sure, but it is older.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I installed the driver then reset, unfortunately when it rebooted, it didn't detect the wireless usb anymore. So I had to do a fresh reinstall.

Comment: No just remove it by `sudo apt-get purge rtlwifi-new-dkms` and install another by `sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms`

Comment: Well The bandwidth has improved. Thank you again for your help and patience. I'm really sorry about the intial formatting of the original question. I am still very new to the linux community